# Управление lpt портом

Tags: c#, lpt

c c# раньше не сталкивался, но есть опыт программирования на java - поэтому и был выбран c#
нужно отправлять данные через lpt порт, думаю использовать SerialPort как это правильно сделать ?

---

при выборе инструментов естественно смотрел в сторону rxtx и javax.comm, но обе они нативные, да и просто захотелось поближе познакомиться с c#

Comment: Странное решение: есть опыт на Java, поэтому решил использовать C#  
Не проще ли найти как работать с LPT с помощью Java ?  
Например так: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Поиск в гугле выводит на inpout32.dll. Сразу нашёлся пример на VB: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15020/Reading-from-Parallel-Port-using-Inpout32-dll — попробуйте перевести на C# или нагуглить подходящий пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4981/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-1-Controlling-LEDs-Light-Emit). SerialPort Вам не подойдёт :-)